# How to format my Perl code such that I can alter my calling from the command window and either test or not test it?

Tags: perl, input, command, prompt, localtime

What I have: To elaborate, I currently have a main function that specifies a source directory and a destination archive directory. At the end of each month, the past month's data must be moved into the archive directory. I have all that figured out and well and down. The sub routine is what picks out the local time with the localtime function and then after I test a few conditions, it returns the previous month and year to be the name of the new folder in the archive directory.

What I need: I have a test setup in the sub routine such that when $test = 1, the test runs and specifies a unique year and month that I can type in, whereas when test = 0, the test doesn't run and the code works normally. I want to be able to write the name of the file into a command line outside of the code and have some sort of initiation to spark whether or not I run a test or not (like perl -e archive.pl 1 to run a test and perl -e arhcive.pl 0 to run the code as normal).

I'm brand new at Perl but here is my sub routine:

```
sub dateDirectory {
    my $lt = localtime();            # establish a variable lt for the localtime (includes, sec, min, hour, mday, mon, year)
    my $year = $lt->year+1900;       # establish a variable year and add 1900 to it as it prints only 100+ value
    my $mon = $lt->mon+1;            # establish a variable mon for month and add 1 as it is a zero-indexed language

    my $test = 1; # establish the test variable to run a unit test if test = 1 and don't run it if test = 0

    if ($test == 1) {
        $year = 2005;
        $mon = 3;
    }

    my $prev_mon = $mon - 1;
    my $prev_year = $year - 1;
    my $prev_yearmonth = "year$prev_mon";

    if ($mon == 1) {
        $prev_mon = 12;
        $year = $prev_year;
        $prev_yearmonth = "$year$prev_mon";
    }

    my $prev_monlength = length($prev_mon);

    if ($prev_monlength == 1) {
        $prev_yearmonth = sprintf "%d%02d", $year, $prev_mon;
    }

    return ($prev_yearmonth);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Miller said, `Getopts::Long` is a great way to supply command line options to your perl program. However, I wanted to add an example of how you would use an argument to set `$test` to 0 or 1.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $test = $ARGV[0];

if ( not defined $test ) {
    die "please supply an argmument";
}

if ( $test == 1 ) {
    print "test mode\n";
} else {
    print "normal mode\n";
}
```

Try calling with it `perl test.pl 0` and `perl test.pl 1`.

Comment: I see the use of Getopts::Long but I think your solution is best suited to my problem. However, I've been playing with this for a few days and can't figure out how to incorporate the input test argument into the main routine while incorporating the conditions in the sub routine. I tried putting
my $test = @_; 
into the sub routine to call my input from the main function but it didn't work.

Comment: `@_` is an array and you are calling it in scalar context. Try `my ($test) = @_;` and if that doesn't work you could post some code and ask another question.

Comment: No that didn't work. I can get it to work perfectly if I include your whole code (minus the use strict and use warnings) into my subroutine where I have all the other conditions. But if I try to use the my $test = $ARGV[0]; part into the main routine, it stops working. Which is why I was trying to call it into the subroutine.

Comment: @user3799015, I'd have to see your code to figure it out. You do have `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of your script right? They point out errors. If you take them out, the errors are still there but the messages are not displayed and they could cause other problems.

Comment: Yes I do. The code functions properly I just don't think it functions quite in the way I'm intending unless I include the entire code in the sub routine. I was just told testing from a sub routine is bad practice.

Answer (score 2):

Use `@ARGV` to access parameters passed to a perl script.

In this case, I'd advise you to use [`Getopts::Long`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html) to capture parameters meant to trigger your special processing:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Getopt::Long;

GetOptions(
    'test'   => \my $test,
);

print $test ? "In Testing mode\n" : "Regular mode\n";
```

And then just execute your script like the following when you want to be in test mode:

```
perl yourscript.pl --test
```

Comment: If I'm just executing my test by inputing --test into the command line, how am I accessing the conditions set by the test?

Comment: Does performing your code with --test just set the value of test equal to 1?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider learning to use CPAN, and install the [DateTime](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime) module.  It makes all sorts of date math easy to do in a correct fashion.

```
use Carp qw< croak >;
use DateTime;

sub dateDirectory {
    my ($year, $month) = @_;

    # croak throws an exception at the calling function.
    croak "dateDirectory requires both year and month or neither be specified\n"
        if (
            ($year && !$month)
         || (!$year && $month)
        );

    # Get default value of "last month", if not specified.
    if( !$year ) {
        my $date = DateTime->now()->subtract( months => 1 );

        $year = $date->year();
        $month = $date->month();
    }

    return "%04d%02d", $year, $month;
}
```

You can write test code that calls dateDirectory with whatever year and month you want.

Comment: I'll be sure to install the module thanks! :) It'll be good to test the code for sure.

Answer (score 0):

I like perl, but I'd used log rotate with cron instead for this basic function.

http://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference/

http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It'd be useful if you posted the relevant quotes from your links in your answer, so users won't have to go searching for them.